# Symfony2 - How to manage permissions with roles by action not by the object

Tags: symfony, permissions, role

I would like to manage the permissions of my roles.
You should know that my roles are stored in the database.
Generally, the permissions are for each object, I will like do the permissions for each action. How would you know?

Answer (score 0):

I think for your use-case [ACL](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/acl.html) would fit the most.

The setup is a bit complex, but there are many benefits.